# To reduce shrinkage, is it wise to mix sanded grout with unsanded grout?

Tags: tile, grout

Is it ok to mix sanded with unsanded grout provided the grout is from the same manufacturer? I'm using Home Depots Polyblend product.

Comment: Why do you feel that grout shrinkage will be a problem? This is normally unnecessary (and could be problematic) for wall tiles with grout joints <= 1/8".

Comment: I tested on scrap tile and found some shrinkage and separation, not much but it was noticeable.